# How to make Canonicals with PHP

Tags: php, seo, canonical-link

I've search around on SO, but can't find an exact answer to my needs.

Generating a URL is pretty easy...

Like so:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" />
```

But, the issue with this is, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` will always fetch the current file in use, so the canonical URL could potentially change.

So it could flick between www.example.com/hello.php and www.example.com/hello/, and many other variations depending on how the user accesses your site.

How do I make it so it's always the same url? (preferably without .php)

Comment: What defines which one is the canonical URL?

Comment: you'd need to use a mod rewrite through Apache for this.

Comment: Well, in the case above it's easy to define, because all variations have been solved statically. https://example.com/the url without .php/. I guess what would solve it is just fetching the URI without .php.

Comment: So, canonical URL means whatever hostname and path is used to fetch the page, without `.php` suffix?

Comment: A canonical can be anything you want it to be. But whatever you set, it must not change the format. In my case, I want https:// example / URI /   without .php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out myself, pretty basic:

```
<?php
$fullurl = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$trimmed = trim($fullurl, ".php");
$canonical = rtrim($trimmed, '/') . '/';
?>
```

Then...

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com<?php echo $canonical ?>" />
```

I'm sure there's different methods, but it works for me.

Comment: But that code marks every variant of an URL as canonical, which is kind of the opposite of what the concept is there for ?
Also you use the HTML link which is supposed to be on NON canonical pages but you link to the same URI used to retrieve that page ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do.

```
<?php

// get the rigth protocol
$protocol = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http';

// simply render canonical base on the current http host ( multiple host ) + requests
echo $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your scripts require a bit of sanitisation, am I right?
I mean, if your page is

```
https://example.com/test.php
```

but a malicious - but harmless - person does

```
https://example.com/test.php/anotherThing.php
```

your canonical would become

```
https://example.com/anotherThing.php
```

you wouldn't want that to happen, though, am I right? Especially if the malicious person is not harmless and does worst things with your urls...

Answer (score 0):

**This will remove query parameters like `?search=abc&page=32`**

Option 1:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');
```

Option 2 (does the same) :

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Then echo

```
echo '<link rel="canonical" href="' . $url . '" />';
```